# Строки в таблице не растягиваются на всю ширину

Tags: css3, html5, table

Не могу понять в чем дело. Использую свойство table-layout: fixed, но строки идут по три на ширину окна браузера, но должны по одной. Может где-то ошибка в html-коде? Битый час сижу над этой проблемой, не могу решить.

```css
table {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" colspan="2">Вид мебели</th>
      <th colspan="6">Доставка</th>
      <th colspan="2">Подъем на этажи</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">В пределах МКАД</th>
      <th colspan="4">Более 1 км от МКАД</th>
      <th>На грузовом лифте</th>
      <th>Ручной</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3" colspan="2">МЯГКИЕ КРЕСЛА, КРЕСЛА КРОВАТИ, МАТРАСЫ</th>
      <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">990 рублей</td>
      <td rowspan="3" colspan="4">30рублей /1км от МКАД, свыше 50км за МКАД - 50рублей/1км</td>
      <td rowspan="3">500 руб.</td>
      <td rowspan="3">100 руб./этаж</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3" colspan="2">ДИВАН ПРЯМОЙ, ТАХТА, КУШЕТКИ</th>
      <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">990 рублей</td>
      <td rowspan="3" colspan="4">30рублей /1км от МКАД, свыше 50км за МКАД - 50рублей/1км</td>
      <td rowspan="3">600 руб.</td>
      <td rowspan="3">200 руб./этаж</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3" colspan="2">УГЛОВЫЕ И МОДУЛЬНЫЕ ДИВАНЫ</th>
      <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">1390 рублей</td>
      <td rowspan="3" colspan="4">30рублей /1км от МКАД, свыше 50км за МКАД - 50рублей/1км</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Бесплатно</td>
      <td rowspan="3">200 руб./этаж</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3" colspan="2">ПУФИКИ, БЕСКАРКАСНАЯ МЕБЕЛЬ, КРЕСЛА-ГРУШИ</th>
      <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">400 рублей</td>
      <td rowspan="3" colspan="4">30рублей /1км от МКАД, свыше 50км за МКАД - 50рублей/1км</td>
      <td rowspan="3">600 руб.</td>
      <td rowspan="3">50 руб./этаж</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3" colspan="2">КОРПУСНАЯ МЕБЕЛЬ. СТЕНКИ,СПАЛЬНИ, ШКАФЫ И Т.Д</th>
      <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">от 900 рублей</td>
      <td rowspan="3" colspan="4">30рублей /1км от МКАД, свыше 50км за МКАД - 50рублей/1км</td>
      <td rowspan="3">Бесплатно</td>
      <td rowspan="3">200 руб./этаж</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3" colspan="2">МАЛЫЕ ФОРМЫ. СТОЛИКИ, КОМОДЫ, ТУМБЫ И Т.Д</th>
      <td rowspan="3" colspan="2">от 690 рублей</td>
      <td rowspan="3" colspan="4">30рублей /1км от МКАД, свыше 50км за МКАД - 50рублей/1км</td>
      <td rowspan="3">700 руб.</td>
      <td rowspan="3">50 руб./этаж</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: **table-layout:fixed** - Ширина колонок в этом случае определяется либо с помощью тега <col>, либо вычисляется на основе первой строки. Если данные о форматировании первой строки таблицы по каким-либо причинам получить невозможно, в этом случае таблица делится на колонки равной ширины. При использовании этого значения, содержимое, которое не помещается в ячейку указанной ширины, будет «обрезано» либо наложено поверх ячейки. Это зависит от используемого браузера, но в любом случае ширина ячейки меняться не будет. Для корректной работы этого значения обязательно должна быть задана ширина таблицы

Comment: Плюс у Вас путаница с атрибутами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотели сделать нечто подобное?

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0
}


/*стили выше добавлены только для этого примера, в реальном проекте используйте normilize.css\reset.css*/

html,
body {
  width: 100%
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

th,
td {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" rowspan="2">Вид мебели</th>
      <th colspan="2">Доставка</th>
      <th colspan="2">Подъем на этаж</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>В пределах МКАД</th>
      <th>Более 1 км от МКАД</th>
      <th>На грузовом лифте</th>
      <th>Ручной</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">МЯГКИЕ КРЕСЛА, КРЕСЛА КРОВАТИ, МАТРАСЫ</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">ПУФИКИ, БЕСКАРКАСНАЯ МЕБЕЛЬ, КРЕСЛА-ГРУШИ </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">ДИВАН ПРЯМОЙ, ТАХТА, КУШЕТКИ</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">КОРПУСНАЯ МЕБЕЛЬ. СТЕНКИ,СПАЛЬНИ, ШКАФЫ И Т.Д</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">УГЛОВЫЕ И МОДУЛЬНЫЕ ДИВАНЫ</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">МАЛЫЕ ФОРМЫ. СТОЛИКИ, КОМОДЫ, ТУМБЫ И Т.Д</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Да, что-то типа этого. Я уже решил данную проблему и сделал совсем по иному, но ваше решение тоже подходит )